# How to escape & sign in excel footer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, escaping

I need to have an excel footer that contains the string "&T". My problem is that when I attempt to do this excel automatically changes it to be "&[Time]". Is there anyway to escape the & to make it display &T as plain text?

Comment: Is your string actually `"&T"` with the quotes, or `$T` without the quotes?  Have you tried it WITH quotes?  Have you tried any of Excel's cell formatting options already?

Comment: My string is without the quotes. If I add the quotes it changes it to "&[Time]" (with the quotes added). What formatting would I change for this footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try one more "&" in your string, so that it is actually "&&T" ?  I have a header in a workbook that had the same issue, and I solved it that way.

Comment: That did it. I should have known to try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the "Wingdings 2" font for capital Z.

just type Z and select it, change to wingdings 2 font.